# Partial Distinct Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects. These objects have a property e.g. "Value".

```
       var lst = new List<TestNode>();

       var c1 = new TestNode()
        {
          Value = "A",
        };

        lst.Add(c1);

        var c2 = new TestNode()
        {
            Value = "A",
        };

        lst.Add(c2);

        var c3 = new TestNode()
        {
            Value = "B",
         };

        lst.Add(c3);

        var c4 = new TestNode()
        {
             Value = "B",
        };

        lst.Add(c4);
```

I would like to say something like:

```
lst.PartialDistinct(x => x.Value == "A")
```

This should only be distinct by predicate and when printing the "Value"s of the resulting IEnumerable the result should be:

```
A
B
B
```

I already found solutions for DistinctBy where it's possible to define a Key-Selector. But the result is then of course:

```
A
B
```

Cyral's first answer did the job. So I accepted it. But Scott's answer is really a PartialDistinct() Method as asked and looks like it solves all my problems.

Ok, thought it's solved with Scott's solution but it's not. Maybe I made a mistake while unit testing... or I don't know. The problem is:

```
if(seen.Add(item))
```

This does not filter out other objects with value "A".I think this is because it relies on referential equality when putting into hashset.

I ended up with following solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PartialDistinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source
            .Where(predicate)
            .Take(1)
            .Concat(source.Where(x => !predicate(x)));
    }
```

Comment: Has the `TestNode` other properties? What should be values of these properties at the single remaining object?

Comment: Are you wanting to perform a distinct on `Value` or a distinct on `TestNode` where `Value == A` plus the normal result set where `Value != A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try finding the elements that match your value, taking the first element of that, and then joining that with all that don't match your value.

```
var match = "A";
var result = lst
    .Where(x => x.Value == match)
    .Take(1)
    .Concat(lst
    .Where(x => x.Value != match))
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Take(1) and Distinct() will have VERY different behaviors if `TestNode` is not filtering only on `Value` in `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. (and I did not -1, I thought your answer was good. The OP was not clear in the question if he wanted a Distinct on `Value` so it is good to have both ways of doing it)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh I see what you mean, I wrote it mistakenly thinking I was calling Distinct() on the value and not the object.

Answer (score 5):

You can group by `Value` and perform 'conditional flattening' using `SelectMany`, i.e. take only one element from 'A' groups and *all* elements from the rest of the groups:

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                .SelectMany(g => g.Key == "A" ? g.Take(1) : g);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to distinct on `TestNode` where `Value == A` plus the normal result set where `Value != A` just do that exact process and wrap it up in to a extension method.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> PartialDistinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        return PartialDistinct(source, filter, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> PartialDistinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        HashSet<T> seen = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (filter(item))
            {
                if (seen.Add(item))
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: second version probably the nicer solution

Comment: @KeithNicholas you are right, I updated the answer and only used the 2nd version.

Comment: Second solution is not working. if(seen.Add(item)) does not filter out objects with "A".

Comment: Well, you either need to pass in a comparer that checks `Value` or override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to compare the property `Value` instead of the default comparision.

Answer (score 0):

Creating two different list and concatenating them is also a way.

```
var answer = lst.Where(val=>val == "A").Select(note=>note.Value).Distinct().Concat(
        lst.Where(node => node.Value == "B").Select(node => node.Value));
```