# Prevent duplicates from array, based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delegates

I have an array of numbers and I need to prevent duplicates. I need to remove all duplicates except one, for each number in the array that is larger than `0`. For example if the input is [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2], the output should be this: [0,0,0,1,2]. Can someone help me? I've tried the code below but I'm getting a result like this [0,1,2].

```
Results.GroupBy(item => item.id).Select(x => x.First());
```

Another example of input and expected output:

```xml
Input:  {[id=0,Name="test0"],[id=0,Name="test0"], [id=1,Name="test1"],[id=1,Name="test1"],[id=1,Name="test1"],[id=2,Name="test2"],[id=2,Name="test2"]}
Output: {[id=0,Name="test0"],[id=0,Name="test0"],[id=1,Name="test1"],[id=2,Name="test2"]}
```

Comment: @John I think they mean they want to remove duplicates > 0

Comment: welcome on board. Please provide some reproducable code you already tried. To improve your question, you may have a look at these articles: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes I expected 3 zeros need to avoid

Comment: You can group on the values then based on the value either take just one or all. `list.GroupBy(x => x).SelectMany(grp => grp.Key > 0 ? grp.Take(1) : grp)` note that would remove duplicates even if they are not all in a row like your example.

Comment: What would you want the output to be if the zeros are dispersed throughout the list, say: `0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618080/partial-distinct-linq

Comment: @MatthewWatson My output should be 0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0.  I'm getting duplicates in the list. If the Id is 0 then i need to skip. if the id is > 0 then i need to filter dulicates

Comment: @juharr Working as expected. To learn can you brief what you exactly doing?.

Comment: It looks like your collection of items has an Id that you want to filter on, but should the result be the items, or the ids?

Comment: If you want the items an option would be to create a `HashSet` of the `Id` type and then do `Results.Where(item => item.id <= 0 || hashSet.Add(item.Id)).ToList();`

Comment: What is unclear about this question? Please explain, so that we can improve it.

Comment: @juharr I have collections like this {[id=0,Name="test0"],[id=0,Name="test0"], [id=1,Name="test1"],[id=1,Name="test1"],[id=1,Name="test1"],[id=2,Name="test2"],[id=2,Name="test2"]}. I need to remove duplicate's only  if id is > 0. o/p should be {[id=0,Name="test0"],[id=0,Name="test0"], [id=1,Name="test1"],[id=2,Name="test2"]]}

Comment: @juharr I tried this list.GroupBy(x => x.id).SelectMany(grp => grp.Key > 0 ? grp.Take(1) : grp). Result is working as expected. But please let me know this method id correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your own extension method that works like the built-in LINQ methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T,bool> predicate)
    {
        HashSet<T> hashset = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach(T item in input)
        {
            if(!predicate(item))
            {
                yield return item;
                continue;
            }
            
            if(!hashset.Contains(item))
            {
                hashset.Add(item);
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is

```
int[] input = new int[] { 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2 };
int[] result = input.DistinctWhere(x => x > 0).ToArray();
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QDpCDF

**EDIT**: If you want to use a property of the objects in your list (like an ID property), you can add some slight modifications to the method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctWhere<T,T2>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T,T2> selector, Func<T2,bool> predicate)
    {
        HashSet<T2> hashset = new HashSet<T2>();
        foreach(T item in input)
        {
            T2 value = selector.Invoke(item);
            if(!predicate.Invoke(value))
            {
                yield return item;
                continue;
            }

            if(!hashset.Contains(value))
            {
                hashset.Add(value);
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is

```
TypeWithId[] input = new TypeWithId[]
{
    new TypeWithId { ID = 0 } , 
    new TypeWithId { ID = 0 } , //... also initialize the other items
};
TypeWithId[] result = input.DistinctWhere(x => x.ID, x => x > 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: It looks like the OPs collection of items has an Id property that they are filtering on and if they want the result to be the items and not the Ids then this wouldn't work without some changes so that it would hash the Ids instead of the actual items.

Comment: @juharr: This can be achieved easily. I added an example how this could be done.

Comment: *"Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'T2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"* Btw instead of `T` and `T2` I would use the names `TSource` and `TKey`, and instead of `selecter`, `keySelector`. Also when accepting selectors, an extra parameter `IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer` may be warranted.